# JSP Suddenly Stopped Sending CSS

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, tomcat

I have a JavaEE project running on tomcat. My JSP is as follows.

It is in my WEB-INF folder and is called through a servlet. I have static content, such as CSS, outside of WEB-INF in my resources folder. Until now, everything was fine - the JSP was accessing the CSS and displaying a lovely webpage, but all of a sudden the style stopped showing up. I have literally no idea why as I didn't change anything. When I view the source and inspect element on multiple browsers on multiple devices, I find that no styles from the CSS are even loaded by the JSP. It's as if the stylesheet doesn't exist.

It is definitely not a problem with my JSP, as I tried `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` as well as tried `<c:url ... />` but neither one worked to fix the problem. I also tried moving the CSS into the WEB-INF directory and that didn't work either.

I created a new JSP using the vanilla JSP template from Intellij and that also seemed to have some issue accessing CSS files, so the issue seems project-wide.

The issue is I have no idea what else could influence the JSP to not get the CSS files.

**Here is my JSP**

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: micro
  Date: 2/6/2020
  Time: 9:19 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value = '/resources/css/mystyles.css' />">
    <title>Chirag Kawediya - Homepage</title>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark container" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="main-logo" >Chirag Kawediya</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-2">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">international movie blog</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">stuff i made</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-12 bg-white border border-dark" style="background-image: url('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/MyPortrait.JPG'); background-size: cover;">
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 bg-white pt-3">
            <h1>welcome</h1>
            <p>I am Chirag Kawediya. I made this website to keep track of my multiple interests simultanenously. As an avid movie-goer,
                I started to watch foreign language films. Now I write about them in my <a href="#">International Movie Blog.</a> In addition,
                I code (mostly in Java), and I will be putting some of my creations on my website <a href="#">here.</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 bg-dark pt-1">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mt-1 mb-auto">recent posts</a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <c:forEach var="post" items="${posts}">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/post?id=${post.id}" class="nav-link"><c:out value="${post.title}" /></a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 bg-white pt-3">
            <h2>about me</h2>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 bg-dark text-white pt-3 pl-4">
                <b>Links</b>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark ml-n3">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="line-height: 0.5 !important;">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Homepage</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">International Movie Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Stuff I Made</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Resume</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 bg-dark text-white pt-3 pl-4">
                <b>Contact Information</b>
                <p>Phone: +1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX</p>
                <p>Email: example@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 bg-dark text-white pt-3 pl-4 pr-auto">
                <b>Other Stuff</b>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark ml-n3">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="line-height: 0.5 !important;">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://coolmathgames.com" class="nav-link">CoolMathGames</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="http://google.com" class="nav-link">Google</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my web.xml in case that is the culprit**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>homepage</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>DBusername</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>DBpassword</param-name>
        <param-value>chirag12</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>uploadFilePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/usr/share/websitestuff</param-value>
    </context-param>

    ...
    a ton of servlet mappings that I edited out
    ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CommentCreator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CommentUploader</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CommentCreator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/new-comment</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

ALSO it looks like the bootstrap css that I reference *is* registered and loaded by the JSP. So, it looks like just the stuff inside my project's webapps folder that I try load is not loaded. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

tl;dr JSP completely ignoring resources that are in webapps folder (or even in WEB-INF) as if they do not exist

**UPDATE:** The problem just got even stranger. I also realized that the server does not even seem to interpret anything that does not end with .jsp unless it is a servlet. If I visit mywebsite.com/page-that-doesn't-exist, I don't get a 404 even though I should. If I visit mywebsite.com/page-that-doesn't-exist.jsp, I do get a 404. Basically, only JSP file endings are not ignored, and the rest are, as far as the webapp goes. I don't really know what this means or how I can fix it.

Comment: In browser open developer console and check is there any error on the network tab for the css.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried that, and got the error "css ignored due to mime type mismatch". I'm not sure what the solution for that would be.

Comment: Did you add a dependency recently? These can potentially change mime types match rules. Depending on your application server, there might also be a global section where mime types are configured. Maybe something changed these settings? You could try adding `<mime-mapping><extension>css</extension><mime-type>text/css</mime-type></mime-mapping>` to your `web.xml` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, mime-mapping did not work. What I did find, though, is that my browser (or server, I am not sure) is only accepting JSPs. If i make my css file into a JSP and put `<%@ page contentType="text/css;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>` at the top it works fine. This is a problem for me, though, as I also want to have html files in my web application for the sake of speed.